# log4j Warn: No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, sbt, log4j

I am writing a code in which I am trying to produce messages using kafka and SBT. It compile but when run's with SBT, I got this error.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I looked online and found out the log4j.properties isn't being found in my classpath. So I went in the folder `etc/sbt` and modify the file `sbtconfig.txt`. I added in it this

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/hduser/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/config/log4j.properties
-Dkafka.logs.dir=/home/hduser/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/logs
```

I tried running the task again but kept getting the same error.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is the content of your `log4j.propertes` file?

Comment: My `log4j.properties` file is the same as this [link](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/log4j.properties).
Do I have to change something in this file?

Comment: That file is for the server, not a producer, and you do not need `kafka.logs.dirs` in your producer either...

Comment: Ok thanks, but it does not solve my problem. How can I Initialize the log4j system properly?

Comment: try to create file `log4j.properties` file in `resources` directory with for example following content:
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to create a log4j.xml file inside the resource folder.

```
<log4j:configuration debug="false">
<!--Console appender -->
<appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
</root> </log4j:configuration>
```

create this file and give a name as log4j.xml inside the resource folder. It will resolve the issue.